# How to exclude specific pattern while using sed

Tags: unix, sed, sh

I have a file which is space separated, I need to convert it to pipe delimited but when it encounters specific patterns in each line, it needs to exclude those patterns while doing sed.

```
a char(30) NOT NULL
b LARGEINT NOT NULL
c TIMESTAMP
d numeric(10, 3)
```

Expected output

```
a|char(30)|NOT NULL
b|LARGEINT|NOT NULL
c|TIMESTAMP|
d|numeric(10, 3)|
```

While replacing the space, need to ignore space in (10, 3) and NOT NULL.
I tried the below but it didn't work

```
sed -ri '|, |!s|\ /\|/g' abc.txt
```

Any help in this regard is appreciated.

Comment: So the output should look like:  a|char(30)|NOT NULL?

Comment: GIve your expected output as well. Do you want to replace space between `char(30)` and `NOT NULL`

Comment: the expected output is a|char(30)|NOT NULL

Comment: He must have a trailing `space` following those two lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood the question correctly, these are requirements:

- Convert input file into three column output with `|` as delimiter
- The third field may be empty
- Input is space delimited, but

  - Third field may contain spaces
  - Second field in input may contain text within `()` which may contain spaces

Following would work for given sample

```
$ cat ip.txt 
a char(30) NOT NULL
b LARGEINT NOT NULL
c TIMESTAMP
d numeric(10, 3)

$ sed -E 's/ +/|/; s/\) */)|/; /\)/!s/ +|$/|/' ip.txt 
a|char(30)|NOT NULL
b|LARGEINT|NOT NULL
c|TIMESTAMP|
d|numeric(10, 3)|
```

- `s/ +/|/` change first occurrence of one or more spaces to `|`
- `s/\) */)|/` handle the troublesome second field first. Change `)` and optional spaces to `)|`

  - of course, assumes, no other field contains `()`
- `/\)/!s/ +|$/|/` for remaining lines, if it doesn't contain `)`, change first occurrence of one or more spaces or end of line to `|`

Answer (score 3):

In GNU awk using [`FPAT`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Splitting-By-Content.html):

```
$ awk '
BEGIN {
    FPAT="([^ ]+)|([^ ]*NOT NULL[^ ]*)|([^ ]*numeric([^)]*)[^ ]*)"  # set FPAT
    OFS="|"                                                         # set OFS
}
{ NF=3; $1=$1 }                                                     # rebuild record (1)
1' file                                                             # and output
a|char(30)|NOT NULL
b|LARGEINT|NOT NULL
c|TIMESTAMP|
d|numeric(10, 3)|
```

(1) `NF=3` sets field count statically to 3 and causes the pipes in the ends of the c and d records.

Comment: Nice usage of `FPAT`, `++`, but still not convinced OP intentionally meant to have `|` at the last two lines though!

Comment: @Inian Don't know about but that I'll fix it anyway.

Answer (score 1):

It's not particularly pretty, but a *two expression* `sed` expression will work,

```
$ sed -e 's/\([^,T]\)[ ]/\1\|/g' file.txt | sed -e 's/\([^O]T\)[ ]/\1\|/'
a|char(30)|NOT NULL
b|LARGEINT|NOT NULL
c|TIMESTAMP
d|numeric(10, 3)
```

If you really want the pipe after `TIMESTAMP` and `)`, you can add a third to the end, e.g.

```
$ sed -e 's/\([^,T]\)[ ]/\1\|/g' file.txt | sed -e 's/\([^O]T\)[ ]/\1\|/' \
-e 's/\([^L]\)$/\1\|/'
a|char(30)|NOT NULL
b|LARGEINT|NOT NULL
c|TIMESTAMP|
d|numeric(10, 3)|
```

But I took the final pipes to be trailing spaces in your input file not present in mine. Either way, it's another way to skin-this-cat.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '/^[cd]/{$NF=$NF"|"}{sub(/ /,"|")sub(/ N/,"|N")}1' file

a|char(30)|NOT NULL
b|LARGEINT|NOT NULL
c|TIMESTAMP|
d|numeric(10, 3)|
```

What happens?
It starts with adding pipes at the end of the line beginning with c or d.

The first sub replace pipe in very first empty space area.

And the second sub put pipe in front of NOT.

Comment: Please edit your answer to include some explanation. Code-only answers do very little to educate future SO readers. Your answer is in the moderation queue for being low-quality.